# jq: print key and value for each entry in an object

Tags: json, jq

How do I get **jq** to take json like this:

```
{
  "host1": { "ip": "10.1.2.3" },
  "host2": { "ip": "10.1.2.2" },
  "host3": { "ip": "10.1.18.1" }
}
```

and generate this output:

```
host1, 10.1.2.3
host2, 10.1.2.2
host3, 10.1.18.1
```

I'm not interested in the formatting, I just can't figure out how to access the key name and value.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

To get the top-level keys as a stream, you can use the [built-in function](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) `keys[]`.  So one solution to your particular problem would be:

```bash
jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k), \(.[$k] | .ip)"'
```

`keys` produces the key names in sorted order; if you want them in the original order, use `keys_unsorted`.

Another alternative, which produces keys in the original order, is:

```bash
jq -r 'to_entries[] | "\(.key), \(.value | .ip)"'
```

#### CSV and TSV output

The @csv and @tsv filters might also be worth considering here, e.g.

```
jq -r 'to_entries[] | [.key, .value.ip] | @tsv'
```

produces:

```
host1   10.1.2.3
host2   10.1.2.2
host3   10.1.18.1
```

#### Embedded objects

If the keys of interest are embedded as in the following example, the jq filter would have to be modified along the lines shown.

Input:

```json
{
  "myhosts": {
    "host1": { "ip": "10.1.2.3" },
    "host2": { "ip": "10.1.2.2" },
    "host3": { "ip": "10.1.18.1" }
  }
}
```

Modification:

```bash
jq -r '.myhosts | keys[] as $k | "\($k), \(.[$k] | .ip)"'
```

Comment: Suppose the ".ip" key had whitespace in it, for example, "ip address", how would escape the quotes surrounding the key, given that you would be on the third level of a quoted string, if that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense, and it's a good question, but forgive me for saying, you could easily have answered it yourself, since the answer is simply to ignore the potential complication.  That is, the normal approach would have been to quote the string-with-spaces, et voilà.

Comment: I had tried that without success. Tried escaping the quotes but it didn't work, hence the question.

Comment: @Saichovsky - I've checked it works in jq 1.4, 1.5, and 1.6.  If you're using jq 1.3, you'd have to write `.["id address"]`, as you would have to do in the normal case anyway.

Answer (score 106):

Came across very elegant solution

```
jq 'with_entries(.value |= .ip)'
```

Which ouputs

```
{
  "host1": "10.1.2.3",
  "host2": "10.1.2.2",
  "host3": "10.1.18.1"
}
```

Here is the jqplay snippet to play with: https://jqplay.org/s/Jb_fnBveMQ

The function `with_entries` converts each object in the list of objects to Key/Value-pair, thus we can access `.key` or `.value` respectively, we're updating (overwriting) every KV-item `.value` with the field `.ip` by using update `|=` operator

Comment: This solution is the exact answer. The selected solution has extras that are helpful but not as exact or elegant. You may want to add a concise explanation and the full command.

Comment: Superb! Many times I used "to_entries[]" simply because I didn't know this one.