# How to select key and sub-object property via jq?

Tags: json, jq

Given the json `filter.json`:

```
{
    "123": {
        "name": "Horst"
    },
    "789": {
        "name": "Bob"
    }
}
```

I want to filter for each key and the name, wanting an output like:

```
"123": "Horst"
"789": "Bob"
```

I tried:

```
jq .[].name,keys < filter.json
```

Yet it gives me faulty output of:

```
"Horst"
"Bob"
[
  "123",
  "789"
]
```

yet I don't know how to "merge" these two outputs to one. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226370/jq-print-key-and-value-for-each-entry-in-an-object) I took the best answer from there a tweaked it a little bit to get the following.

```
$ jq 'to_entries[]| {(.key): .value.name}' < /tmp/filter.json
{
  "123": "Horst"
}
{
  "789": "Bob"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ jq -r 'keys[] as $key | "\"\($key)\": \"\(.[$key].name)\""
```

produces:

```
"123": "Horst"
"789": "Bob"
```