# Get all entries with their respective keys using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

The JSON structure I'd like to process looks like :

```json
{
 "data1": "some data",
 "data2": "some data",
   "key1": {
     "data3": "some data",
     "data4": "some data"
   },
   "key2": {
     "data5": "some data"
   }
}
```

And what I would like jq to output (in order to extract and set variables using eval) :

```
data1="some data"
data2="some data"
key1_data3="some data"
key1_data4="some data"
key2_data5="some data"
```

I already tried using something like `to_entries` to get `.key` and `.value` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34226370/jq-print-key-and-value-for-each-entry-in-an-object)) but I didn't have much success parsing it.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `paths` function to get paths to each of the scalar values, then `getpath` to retrieve the value that path leads to. `$p` records the paths for later use.

```
$ jq -r 'paths(scalars) as $p | "\($p|join("_"))=\"\(getpath($p))\""' tmp.json
data1="some data"
data2="some data"
key1_data3="some data"
key1_data4="some data"
key2_data5="some data"
```

(Answer based on information found at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/78.)

---

Showing how two of the key steps work in more detail:

```
$ jq -cr 'paths(scalars)' tmp.json
["data1"]
["data2"]
["key1","data3"]
["key1","data4"]
["key2","data5"]
$ jq -r 'paths(scalars) | join("_")' tmp.json
data1
data2
key1_data3
key1_data4
key2_data5
```